# SharePoint 2013 Search File Shares

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, result-source

I have a search service application that has 2 content sources - one for the SharePoint Sites and one for File Shares. When I perform a search from the Search Center the results can show documents from both Sites and Shares. How can I show only the results from the Sites or only the results from the Shares?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure separate Result Sources and add them to the search web parts.

[This blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx#HowConfigure) shows how to create a new Result Source except that on the **Build Your Query** step you will filter your query to the Content Source as opposed to the ContentClass or Path that are used on the post.

You can then create as many search result pages as you want, filtering for your custom Result Sources as per [this second post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/13/how-to-add-a-customized-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

Comment: After I built my query, when I hit "Save" I got the following

Comment: Exchange Source URL - "You must enter a value for this required field" and Source URL Open Source - "You must enter a value for this required field".

Comment: I just entered http:// for both and I was able to save. Will this be a problem?

Comment: I think you might have chosen the wrong protocol on the new Result source screen - Try "Local SharePoint"

Comment: I deleted my result source and built a new query. This time Save worked without asking for a value in Exchange and Source URL. I configured the Search Results Web Part to use the new result source. However, when I try to do a query I get no results! I tried going through the procedures severl times but still no results on a query.

Comment: What did you set as the Query for the result source?

Comment: I did use "Local Sharepoint"

Comment: {searchTerms?}path:file://servername/share. When I TEST here I get the results expected

Comment: If you copied and pasted the content, try adding a space before "path:" I tested on one of my Dev sites and the lack of space there can cause the behavior described. If you didn't I need to think some more.

Comment: Adding the space worked! However this search center will now only display results from the File Share. What I really wanted to accomplish was to have the default Search Center have a Result Type option on the left that included File Shares. So that the query would first show all results both SharePoint Sites and File Shares, then select the File Shares Result Type to show only the File Shares results. It this is not possible then the only solution I see is to have 2 seperate Search Centers!

Comment: If you look at the second link, you will see how  to add new Verticals to the search. Then in your search center, under the search box, people choose which result source they ant to use, and the results will be displayed as desired =]

You will end up with multiple search result pages in the same search center, one per result source.