# Indexing a network shared drive

Tags: search, index

I have a shared drive on the network willing to expose to sharepoint so the users will be able to searcch its content from sharepoint.

Comment: What is your question? Do you experience a problem when indexing the share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new content source and specify to index a file share here (Search Service Application > Content Sources > New Content Source).
[image: Select File Share under Content Source Type]

Make sure that your default content access account has access to that share/folders as well.
[image: Account to use for indexing]

In case you want / need to provide a different account to crawl this share you can specify one within the Crawl Rules (Search Service Application > Crawl Rules)

Make sure that the permissions within the share and all of its (sub-)folders are correct since indexing a file share can make it much easier for people to find files that they normally don't have access to.

[image]

If the user can access the SHARE and Folder C but not Folder A and Folder B he/she normally can't access files in Folder C without knowing the exact path.
Once indexed in SharePoint it is an easy thing to find files from Folder C. (I hope that was somewhat understandable - English isn't my 1st language)

These also might be useful:

- https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/10/07/search-content-source-in-sharepoint.aspx
- [SharePoint 2013 Search File Shares](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118226/sharepoint-2013-search-file-shares)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1ce8ad/configure-sharepoint-2013-search-to-crawl-files-in-share-fol/

Comment: thx it is perfectly fine ! I'll come back to you if I need anything else !! Great!

Comment: Hello back,
Folder was not found error ??

Comment: this is my folder could it be the space in the naming ?

Comment: Or maybe it is a permission issues .?

Comment: Where do you get the error and what is the path? Have you checked that the crawl account can access the share and the underlying folder(s)?
a space in the share name (e.g. \\Fileserver\My Folder) shouldn't be an issue for the content source.

Comment: When I put file://192.168.222.3/New-Share I get no error but nothing is indexed and when I add a folder name to the path I get the not found error

Comment: I checked from my machine with a shared folder it worked! makes me think that the issue is a permission wise one